# How can I hide the validation/marker error bar on the right in IntelliJ Idea 10?

Tags: view, window, intellij-idea

The right side validation bar that shows yellow markers for warnings and red markers for errors.

Answer (score 10):

There is no way to hide it as it's [combined with the scrollbar](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/Scrollbars+FAQ).

However, you can adjust the severity settings for errors and warnings so that they are not displayed in the stripe as marks in `Settings` | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts` | `General`:

- Error
- Warning
- Weak Warning

Disable **Error Stripe Mark** checkbox for the elements above.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In Idea 12 there is a checkbox "Error Stripe Mark", which does exactly what was asked: shows/hides the colored marks in the scroller.